# Salesforce Lightning make checkbox checked using jQuery

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, inputcheckboxes

I am wanting to iterate over two arrays, and I want to set checkboxes to checked whenever items in the array match.  I have no problem with the iteration, and I can change the checkbox with the name to checked, but it doesn't show as checked on the front end.  my code is this:

CMP

```
<aura:component controller="MyProfileApex" 
            implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">    

<ltng:require styles="<<styles>>" 
              scripts="<<scripts>>"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />


<aura:attribute name="getGifting" type="sobject[]"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.getGifting}" action="{!c.handleRoleChange}"/>

     <aura:iteration items="{!v.getGifting}" var="gift">
          <ui:inputCheckbox class="thisClass" name="{!gift.Display_Name__c}" click="{!c.RunGiftList}" value="checked"/>
          <ui:outputText class="thisClass" value="{!gift.Display_Name__c}"/>
     </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

JS

```
handleRoleChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var curRoles = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    var theResult = component.get("v.getGifting");
    for (var i = 0; i < theResult.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < curRoles.length; j++) {
            if (theResult[i].Display_Name__c == curRoles[j]) {
                console.log('--' + curRoles[j] + '--');
                $('input[name=' + curRoles[j] + ']').attr('checked', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be firing correctly.  Console log shows the value I expect, and when I inspect element on the checkbox, it shows as Checked, but the checkbox is not checked... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or what I have not included in my code?

Thanks,
Logan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ui:inputCheckbox` is not a standard `html` element. You can't use `jQuery` to change any of it's attributes like that.

What you can do is bind it's `value` attribute to your `getGifting` array and set that to `true` or `false` as required.

Something like this:

```
if (theResult[i].Display_Name__c === curRoles[j]) {
    theResult[i].value = true;
}
else {
    theResult[i].value = false;
}
```

And bind to this value:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox class="thisClass" name="{!gift.Display_Name__c}" click="{!c.RunGiftList}" value="{!gift.value}"/>
```

Your attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="getGifting" type="sobject[]" default="[{'Display_Name__c':'1','value':true},{'Display_Name__c':'2','value':true}]"/>
```

Your other alternative is to use a standard `html` input - you will then be able to set that - although there is no real need to use jQuery if you are only using it for this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Caspar.  In your attribute, it almost looks like you are making a push in an array, which makes sense, but wouldn't that be more of an amendment to an array than a binding?  I wasn't able to get the binding to work, but I don't know if it is due to both of my lists being dynamic... the example I gave was for illustration only.  And yes, using the HTML input works just fine with my code, but I felt that there was a better alternative to the HTML input.

Comment: You need to push to the array as in my example and then call `component.set("v.getGifting",theResult);` to get the bindings to run.